# uploading files using python to a Django server

Tags: python, django

I have a simple view which receives files form users. I've tested it with my browser and it works okay.

On the other hand, I have a python and tested it against requestb.in and I can see the multipart/form-data and a http response code 200. So, both my view in receiving and storing files and the script in uploading multipart data work fine.

**My problem being:** When I use my script to upload a file to the view, even though I get http status code 200, I see no files being stored on the disk while in case of using the browser I do. What would be the problem you think? Here are my model, view and script:

**models.py:**

```
class FileUploads(models.Model):
    uploads = models.FileField()
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import FileUploads

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUploads
        fields = ['uploads']
```

**views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def upper(request):
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    context = {'title': 'welcome', 'form': form}
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context = {'form': form, 'title': 'thanks'}'
    return render(request, 'upform.html', context)
```

**Python script up.py:**

```
import requests
f = open('C:\\Users\\Amir\\Desktop\\snow.jpg', 'rb')
urls='http://127.0.0.1:8000/upper'
r=requests.post(urls, files= {'a':f})
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `files= {'uploads':f}` ?

Comment: @Anentropic Ohhh my god, Thank you, I spent almost 5 hours today to figure out the problem. Yes that was the problem. Thank you again.

Comment: @Anentropic BTW, How can I provide my script with csrt protection, if it is included inside a view, would it suffice to add csrf_protect decorator?

Comment: Django has csrf enabled by default, so just remove the `@csrf_exempt` decorator from the view

Comment: @Anentropic You've been dramatically helpful, thanks; I thought since I am posting the file out side a form with no csrf tag it might not work.

Comment: no it's the other way around, csrf will prevent those unprotected 'ad hoc' post requests from succeeding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
import requests
f = open('C:\\Users\\Amir\\Desktop\\snow.jpg', 'rb')
urls='http://127.0.0.1:8000/upper'
r=requests.post(urls, files= {'uploads':f})
print(r.status_code)
```

...the name of the file in the dict passed to `requests.post` needs to match the field name in the Django form :)